# Summation of a series evaluation using fourier series

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Is there any procedure to simplify summation of a series, such as,

$$\begin{align}S &=1-\frac 1 3+\frac 1 {10}-\frac 1 {42}+\frac 1 {210}-\frac 1 {1320}+.....=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!(2n+1)}\end{align}$$

using *fourier series* expansion, or any criteria should also be given?

If this type of questions has already been asked, please send the link.

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{}}$

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{%
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over n!\pars{2n + 1}}} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{\pars{-1}^{n} \over n!}\int_{0}^{1}x^{2n}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{\pars{-x^{2}}^{n} \over n!}\,\dd x
=
\int_{0}^{1}\expo{-x^{2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{{\root{\pi} \over 2}\on{erf}\pars{1}}
\approx 0.7468 \\ &
\end{align}

$\ds{\on{erf}}$ is the [Error Function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/7.2.E1).

Comment: Thank you sir @Felix Marin , it's realy helpful. But this is just an example, i want these type of series solution using **Fourier Series**.

Comment: @DlIfE Thanks. I'll think about it.